# masonry + infinite scroll + anchor point

Tags: javascript, anchor, jquery-masonry

i am currently developing my website and i'm a bit stuck.
how can use masonry with infinite scroll and an anchor point?

in the anchor point, when you click a link, you go to the part where the anchor point is.

this is in the header.

```
<li> <a href="">aaa</a> </li>
<li> <a href="">bbb</a> </li>
<li> <a href="">ccc</a> </li>
```

now when you click the link, it should go to the specified link in the main content

Comment: Masonry probably won't work with you very much, but there should be a way to do this.  Put some JavaScript on the link that knows which section the anchor is located in, and have it tell Masonry which block to load?

Answer (score 1):

I think anchor point linking is not possible with the *infinite scrolling* technique. It is only possible on pages that are loaded from the server already. This is not the case with an infinite scrolling page.